# ref and cref point to page of label, not label

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, ref

I have the case that `\ref` (also `\cref`) point to the page of the label, but not directly the label.

How can I make it point to the label directly?

Example which uses the [ICML 2021 template](https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2021/Styles/icml2021_style.zip):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{icml2021}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
\label{sec:intro}
Intro.

\section{Conclusion}
As seen in section \ref{sec:intro}.

\end{document}
```

It seems to be related to the ICML template. When I comment out the `\usepackage{icml2021}`, it works.

Comment: As you know, you should add a minimal example. But typically this means a \phantomsection is missing ...

Comment: That `\ref{sec:intro}` seems to work as exepected. In my Evince it moves me right above `1 Intro`. To be move obvious I added `\newpage test \newpage` to the `Conclusion` on a separate page. Please specify exactly which latex installation you are using.

Comment: @daleif: I use Texlive 2018 (on MacOSX). So, when the Intro section is in the middle of the page, it jumps exactly there to the middle? For me, it just jumps to the page, but not exactly to the place.

Comment: To me it jumps such that `1 Intro` is right at the top of the page (this of course depends on the viewer and your zoom.

Comment: I just noticed, when I swap the order of `icml2021` and `hyperref`, it works correctly.